# Activity is receiving Data But Not displaying

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am passing string from activity A to B and then I will get data back from Activity B in A. ThereFore, I used startActivityForResult().I always get "IS not Null". I am receiving the data but I can't view that data in the text view on Acitivity B. I am posting the code please tell me what's wrong.

Activity A (SendData):

```
Intent data= new Intent(SendData.this, RecieveData.class);
Bundle check = new Bundle();

check.putString("UmerData", cheese);
medt.setText(cheese);
data.putExtras(check);
startActivityForResult(data, 5);
```

Activity B(ReceiveData):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recievedata);
    InitializeFoo();
    if(getIntent()!=null)
    {
        rt1.setText("Is not Null");
                    //Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();

        //rt1.setText(got.getString("UmerData"));
    }
}
```

PS:
I made changes in Activity B to see if I am getting string. Still it is displaying "Is not Null" Which means I am not getting string. But I don't know why this is not displaying.
Here is the code:

```
Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();
String ss= got.getString("UmerData");
if(getIntent()!=null && ss==null )
{
    //Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();
    //rt1.setText(got.getString("UmerData"));
    rt1.setText("Is not Null");
}
```

This is in Activity B:

```
private void InitializeFoo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG);
    rt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rt1);
    rt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rt2);
    rec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Return);
    Rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rec.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your activity B extending Activity?

Comment: Nope. It is not extending any custom activity

Comment: The code you have commented out is correct.  Which piece returns null, `getExtras()` or `getString()`?

Comment: I am not sure about that.let me check!

Comment: @Devunwired I updated my question and I am receiving string but I don't know why activity B is not shwoing it.

Comment: I don't see any code where your String extra is attached to a TextView to be displayed...it's still commented out.

Comment: i know.. i uncommented that but its not working

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post all of activity b.. I cannot see the initialization of all of your views.. Have you tried using a debugger to check for values as you go?

Comment: Please check my question I have updated it. I don't know why i am not getting a string

Answer (score 0):

If you add the extras using putExtras(Bundle) you'll need to include the package name in the key of your value pairs. Referring to the documentation:

"Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

You can always use

```
data.putExtra("UmerData", cheese);
```

Answer (score 0):

So there were two main errors. 
First one is that in SendData, right before calling RecieveData, the value of cheese you were setting to the intent was null, that was the main reason you were receiving null in the second activity. 
The following code has to be for those cases, so out of the "if" brackets:

```
cheese = Dt.getText().toString();
```

The other thing (which actually is ok in the code you put up there) is that you were setting the bundle "check" as an extra itself (by calling putExtra(....)) instead of as a bundle made out of a key - value pair (by calling putExtras(...)).

It's tested an received the right value in both places.
For clarification I attach the problematic Activity.

```
package com.umer.practice2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SendData extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText Dt;
    Button Dbut, result;
    TextView medt;
    String cheese;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.data);

    InitializeShit();
    }

    private void InitializeShit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Dt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Det);
    Dbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sna);
    result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sfr);
    medt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Med);

    Dbut.setOnClickListener(this);
    result.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cheese = Dt.getText().toString();
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.Sna:

        Bundle send = new Bundle();

        send.putString("UmerData", cheese);
        Intent foo = new Intent(SendData.this, RecieveData.class);

        foo.putExtras(send);

        startActivity(foo);
        break;

        case R.id.Sfr:
        Intent data = new Intent(SendData.this, RecieveData.class);
        Bundle check = new Bundle(); // NOT IN TRAVIS CODE

        check.putString("UmerData", cheese);// NOT IN TRAVIS CODE
        medt.setText(cheese);// NOT IN TRAVIS CODE
        data.putExtras(check);// NOT IN TRAVIS CODE
        startActivityForResult(data, 5);
        break;
    }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle roti = new Bundle();
        roti = data.getExtras();
        String ch = roti.getString("String");
        medt.setText(ch);
    }
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.